# linq groupjoin does not generate expected sql

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am currently not getting the expected results from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version 1.1.1.

[image: Tables definition]

There is currently a Story with **Id = 1** which has 0 Votes. I m trying to get `GroupJoin` to return an object where if there are no votes, the `Story` object is not null and the `Votes` list is either empty or null (I think it will be empty)

I have come up with this query in c#:

```
var storyVotes = await StoriesDbContext.Stories.GroupJoin(StoriesDbContext.Votes,
                                                          s => s.Id,
                                                          v => v.StoryId,
                                                          (s, v) => new { Story = s, Votes = v })
                                                          .Where(dict => dict.Story.Id == storyId && (dict.Votes == null || dict.Votes.Any(vo => vo.UserId == userId)))
                                                          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**Edit**: As Christos pointed out, the above C# did not compile. I made an editing mistake when I posted the code. The above now correctly represents the code and the result is still the same.

`storyVotes` is null in this situation. I'm a little confused.

[image: linqpad results]

LinqPad returns the result I expect. It returns the `Story` object and the a list (with 0 items).

The query I run directly on the DB also returns the results.

```
SELECT s."Id" as StoryId, v."Id" as VoteId
FROM "Stories" s
left outer JOIN "Votes" v on s."Id" = v."StoryId"
WHERE v."UserId" = 'fa157323-c4b2-4d8a-b7fc-c38988405f61' or v."UserId" is null
and s."Id" = 1;
```

[image: pgadmin 3 results]

According to Application Insights, EF generates this query

```
SELECT "s"."Id", "s"."CreatedDate", "s"."Description", "s"."DescriptionMarkdown", "s"."ModifiedDate", "s"."Score", "s"."Title", "s"."Upvotes", "s"."Url", "s"."UserId", "s"."UserIsAuthor", "v"."Id", "v"."CommentId", "v"."CreatedDate", "v"."ModifiedDate", "v"."StoryId", "v"."UserId"
FROM "Stories" AS "s"
LEFT JOIN "Votes" AS "v" ON "s"."Id" = "v"."StoryId"
WHERE "s"."Id" = @__storyId_0
ORDER BY "s"."Id"
```

It doesn't seem to take into consideration the `&& (dict.v == null || dict.v.Any(vo => vo.UserId == userId)` part of the where clause.

Can you explain why this is happening and explain how I can achieve the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this

```
dict.v == null || dict.v.Any(vo => vo.UserId == userId
```

should change to this

```
dict.Votes == null || dict.v.Any(vo => vo.Votes.UserId == userId)
```

(as you already have done for `dict.Story`). To be honest with you, I wonder why the compiler didn't inform that the first is not correct. Where `v` is coming from? You make a projection of the grouped items and each projection has two properties, `Story` and `Votes`. Where `v` then comes from? It's not clear to me.

Regarding the LINQPad, note there that your projection has two properties...`s` and `v`...

**UPDATE**

By looking more carefully your query in LINQPad I noted that

```
dict.v.Any(vo => vo.Votes.Id == 1)
```

That changes the things ! In the query you mention that there is a problem the corresponding predicate is:

```
dict.Votes.Any(vo => vo.UserId == userId)
```

So you compare the results from two different queries.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the pasted code definitely does not represent what I have. I will update it right now